# Вывести ближайшую дату доставки php

Tags: php, веб-программирование, дата

Нужно вывести правильную дату получения товара.
Есть поставщики:
1) кока-кола. Может доставить товар через 2 дня, со дня заказа. Если заказ выполнен ДО 16:00. Если после, то добавляем +1 день.
2) Липтон. Может доставить товар через 3 дня, со дня заказа. Если заказ выполнен ДО 12. Если после добавляем +1 день.
В выходные дни доставка не осуществляется. Их нужно пропускать

Пример. Я в Пн. 19.03.2018 в 14:00 делаю заказ кока-колы. Значит через 2 дня она прийдет. Время получения товара 21.03.2018. Если после 16:00, то дата получения. 22.03.2018.

Не могу справится с выходными днями. То есть, если я делаю заказ кока-колы в Пятницу(23.03.2018)Пт. в 14:00, вывести нужно дату 27.03.2018.  Нужно не учитывать выходные дни. +2 дня для рабочих дней.

Если я делаю заказ Липтон(24.03.2018)Сб 10:00, вывести нужно 28.03.2018

********************************************** РЕШЕНИЕ ***********************************************
Спасибо за ответы. Пришла голову мысль. Решил следующим образом. Поместил в массив две недели(днями), при этом в массив не попали выходные (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6) Массив $work_days Далее с помощью задания ключа, вывел нужный мне день. Если доставка через 2 дня, то беру второй индекс массива.

```
    $time_now = date('H:i'); // текущее время
    $date_now = date('d-m-Y'); // текущая дата

    $work_days = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $i . " days"));
        if(!$this->isWeekend($date)){
            $work_days[] = $date;      // получаем 30 дней без выходных
        }
    }

    if($delivery_time >= $time_now) {
        $delivery_date = $work_days[$delivery_date_day];
    } else {
        $delivery_date_day += 1;
        $delivery_date = $work_days[$delivery_date_day];
    }

    return $delivery_date;
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете решить всю проблему за вас) У вас есть наработки? Например как вы хотите определять рабочие и праздничные дни?

Answer (score 1):

Определить метку субботы и воскресенья
Если метка доставки попадает в этот интервал, то +n дней
Определить метки (Вывод для примера)

```
// Начало субботы
$date =  date("H:i d.m.Y", strtotime("next saturday"));
echo $date;
// Конец воскресенья
$date =  date("H:i d.m.Y", strtotime("next sunday 23:59:59"));
echo $date;
```